# How do I list my GCP projects under No Organization using the Resource Manager API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-iam

I can't seem to find a proper filter for the [Project List](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) API method to list only the projects which I have access to but are under No Organization.

Is there a filter for this?
What would be the way to achieve this?.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#python) you should be able to use filters to check whether a project belongs to a parent (organization). Through the cli this works:

```
gcloud projects list --filter="parent.id.yesno(yes='Yes', no='No')=No"
```

This would also work:

```
gcloud projects list --filter="parent.id:None"
```

The python equivalent would then be:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1beta1', credentials=credentials)

filter = "parent.id:None"
projects = service.projects().list(filter=filter).execute()
```

Answer (score 2):

I’m afraid there’s no straightforward way to achieve this. The filter would have to match a “parent.id” or a “parent.type” property, which in the case of projects without organization it doesn’t exists (they don’t have a “parent” attribute).

**It would have to be done in two steps:**

1.- List all the projects using the mentioned [Project List method](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list).

2.- Go through each of the projects using the [Project Get method](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/get) and checking that the attribute “parent” exists, if the attribute exists it means it belongs to an organization (or a folder), else, it doesn’t.

**Example of the Project Get response with organization:**

```
{
  "projectNumber": "4444444444",
  "projectId": "my-project-id",
  "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
  "name": "my-project-name",
  "createTime": "2019-04-05T06:57:37.142Z"
  "parent": {
    "type": "organization",
    "id": "5555555555”
  }

}
```

**Example of the Project Get response without organization:**

```
{
  "projectNumber": "4444444444",
  "projectId": "my-project-id",
  "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
  "name": "my-project-name",
  "createTime": "2019-04-05T06:57:37.142Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the filter "-parent.type:folder" (with the dash at the beginning and with no parent.id parameter) should address the issue.

I have tried the API [1] using this filter and got no-organization projects.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list

Comment: I tried out with that filter but I got the list with all the projects (the ones with organization and the ones without it), can you double check making sure you have access to both types of projects? (org projects an non-org projects)