# Is there a simpler way to list GCP projects **not** in an Organization?

Tags: gcloud

I'm looking for a way to list projects that are **not** in an Organization (or Folder).

`gcloud projects list ...` returns a list of [Project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects#Project) and the only obvious indicator that the project is not part of an Organization (or Folder) is the absence of a `parent` property.

I've been unable to find a way to `--filter` the results to exclude projects without a property.

I discovered the `yesno` transform that's part of `--format` which, combined with the `csv` formatter gives me results that I can then `grep` and `cut`:

```sh
gcloud projects list \
--format='csv[no-heading,separator=":"](parent.yesno(yes="Y",no="N"),projectId)' \
| grep ^N: \
| cut -d: -f2
```

But I'd like a way to do this solely using `gcloud`.

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin per this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62424806/12767257), either one of this following commands should help you: `gcloud projects list --filter="parent.id.yesno(yes='Yes', no='No')=No"` or `gcloud projects list --filter="parent.id:None"`. I gave it a try in both and it seemed to work properly. Could you please give it a try and check if they help you?

Comment: Aha! The first (`=No`) works but the second does not. Please post as the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin glad to hear it helped you! I posted it as an answer. Please, consider accepting/upvoting it, as it helped you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As talked in the comments, the solution to return the list of projects without an organization is to run a `gcloud` command that filter by the parent, using the `yesno` option. As clarified in this similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62424806/12767257), the command that can be used to achieve that is the following.

```
gcloud projects list --filter="parent.id.yesno(yes='Yes', no='No')=No"
```

As the `parent` is the relation of a project being under an organization, this command filters when a project doesn't have a parent.